# How to force uploading file from camera without choosing in gallery on IOS?

Tags: html, ios

I wanna force uploading file from camera without choosing in gallery on IOS, I have tried to use this code but it just work on android, not IOS (Safari):

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Comment: I'm guessing this won't ever become a feature as `getUserMedia` will supersede it.

Answer (score 3):

That is possible.

Solution A(better compatibility):

1. Create a video element, and streams data from your camera to it using `getUserMedia`.
2. Create a canvas element, which renders what the video element renders.
3. Capture image from the canvas element.

Solution B(easier):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture />
```

Tested on iOS 12 Safari

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that much access from a website, so you can only ask for images from camera roll or 3rd party sharing enabled apps. like google drive, dropbox...